# Dual Job by a Professor in Europe

Tags: career-path, professorship, assistant-professor

I have seen many professor are working in a research institute and also a full-time professor at a University. How is it feasible? Are they involve in the dual job and getting a salary from a research institute and university?

Comment: Some such institutes are part of a university. And sharing relationships are possible in other cases.

Comment: @Buffy - not just possible but by design.

Comment: At least in Germany, non-university research institutes cannot award PhDs.  That is one reason why many group leaders at such institutions also have a university affiliation.

Answer (score 6):

I work at a government research institution in Germany. We consist of a number of institutes.

In the last decade, our president has worked on strengthening ties to close-by universities (we have institutes at different locations). As a result, there are now strategic cooperations in place. The most important one being that new institute leaders simultaneously become full professors (not "full-time professor[s]") at one of these universities. They have teaching duties but are not paid by the university (although they have a budget at the university).

Similar arrangements were in place at another research institution I've previously worked at (and to my knowledge at basically all of them, i.e., Max-Planck, Leibniz, Helmholtz, and Fraunhofer institutes).

Comment: The not full time is probably the important thing to note here. In fact I think EU worker protection laws put a hard nominal limit of 48h work per week (on average) on everyone, so hiring someone for a second full time position would actually be illegal here.

Comment: @mlk I don't really know but technically it's probably not even a second position.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is most likely *not* a second position, but a honorary appointment or the like.  Except in setups like the "Jülicher Modell", which is significantly more compicated (but there is still no double salary).

Comment: @user151413 It's not honorary. The university has seats in the hiring committee.

Comment: @Roland What kind of setting are we talking about?  Helmholtz or Max Planck Directors can certainly be hired without the participation of a university. -- I think overall there are *lots* of different setups (and subtleties, like whether people are hired by the university and paid by the research institute, or directly hired by the research institute, etc.), while your answer does it make look like there's one "typical" setup.